# What weapons are stopped by Active Protection?

Tags: battlefield-4

The description for Active Protection includes the following:

> When this system is activated it will sense incoming missile and rocket threats and detonate them before they reach the vehicle.

I've observed that Active Protection also blocks jets' and attack boats' cannons even though these are not really missiles and rockets. However, it *doesn't* seem to block rockets from attack helicopters.

Active Protection can be buggy -- especially when your vehicle is in motion -- so it's especially difficult to tell what it blocks and doesn't block in the heat of battle.

So what else (if anything) does Active Protection block? For example, would Active Protection protect you from C4 if it's active when the C4 is detonated? I know that wouldn't make any sense but the Active Protection implementation doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I believe I have seen it block other tanks main cannon as well, but like you said, it can be hard to really tell, since there tends to be multiple threats all coming in at once.  My suggestion would be to get in a private (or just empty) server with a buddy and test everything you can think of one by one.

Comment: @GeneralMike Yes, it blocks the main cannon from other tanks, TOW missiles, the main weapon on IFVs, JDAMs, etc. It just has odd behavior when it comes to jet cannons and attack helicopter rockets so I was hoping someone knew of a complete list of weapons that are supposed to be blocked.